# Twitter API and OAuth - PHP

Tags: php, curl, twitter, oauth

I've read through the documentation for using the APIs and I'm not quite sure how to incorporate OAuth into my current API calls.  Right now, I just use...

```
file_put_contents("my_url");
```

... to get the JSON.  Is there a way to add the OAuth credentials to that call or will I have to switch to using curl or some other method?

Comment: which api are you using? I personally like `tmhOAuth`

Comment: Better to use a library designed to do the job, check out [PHP OAuth Lib](https://github.com/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib)

Comment: I'm using the Search API but I'm exploring the others as well.  Right now, the Search API is sufficient though.  I'd prefer to write something instead of using a framework.  I don't know much about OAuth so I don't want to default to using a framework without first learning the base line code.

Comment: The answer no longer works as of 11th June 2013 due to the retirement of the 1.1 API.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer to my question was to use [stream_context_create](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) as an additional argument to file_get_contents since the OAuth parameters get passed in the request headers.

```
$opts = array(
'http'=>array(
'method'=>"GET",
'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
          "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n" .
          "OAuth-Token: xyz\r\n"
 )
);

file_get_content('my url',stream_context_create($opts));
```

The above is not an exact example as its context dependent.  But the `stream_context_create()` function is how you'd dictate what headers are sent when using `file_get_contents()`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a library, there are many good ones listed [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#php)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the use, sometimes you don't need to bother with OAuth and official Twitter API so here is another lib you won't find in their list :) https://github.com/fbparis/TweetFuck